# Somar strings de uma expressão regular

Tags: php, regex

Boa noite, gostaria de encontrar uma maneira de somar duas strings dentro de uma expressão regular usando *php*. Ex:

```
$texto = "
|5,00|7,00||
|10,00|2,00||
|3,00|30,00||";
```

```
...('/\|(.*)\|(.*)\|/', '|$1|$2|[X=$1+$2]', $texto);
```

Andei pesquisando, mas não encontrei nenhuma maneira de fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$texto = "
|5,00|7,00||
|10,00|2,00||
|3,00|30,00||";                       // "texto" da pergunta

$texto= str_replace(",",".",$texto);  // locales (ver @ValdeirPsr)

$b=preg_replace('/\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|/e', '"$0" . ($1+$2) ', $texto );
echo $b;
?>
```

Ao substituir o segundo argumento de `preg_replace` irá conter strings como

`"|5,00|7,00|" . (5,00 + 7,00)`

que após calculadas dão `|5,00|7,00|12`

#### Update: ignorem esta resposta

Embora correta e apesar de funcionar em muitas versões de Php, a opção `/e` foi descontinuada a partir da versão Php7 pelo que não é um bom caminho a seguir...

Penso que nas versões mais recente o recomendado seria

```
$b=preg_replace_callback(
    '/\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|/',
    function($m){return $m[0]. ($m[1]+$m[2]); },
    $texto
);
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, obrigado. Opps, pelos vistos tenho uma versão mais antiga... (PHP 5.6.9-1 )

Comment: Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$m' (T_VARIABLE) in [...][...] on line 10   LINHA 10 >>>   function($m){retrun $m[0]. ($m[1]+$m[2]); },

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, obrigado, não vai mais vinho para este copo: "return" e não "retrun"...

Comment: hehehe, tem mais Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in [...][...] on line 10

Comment: faça teste aqui http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, obrigado pela sugestão: ajuda!. Comigo funciou bem. (não esquecer de fazer a substituição dos "," por "." incluída na resposta inicial)

Comment: show, agora sim poso dar +1 :)    https://ideone.com/unD8bq

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível realizar opções em com `Regex`. As expressões regulares servem basicamente para identificar e retornar  determinados valores.

No seu caso, além do `Regex`, é utilizar duas funções do `PHP`: [preg_match_all](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) para capturar os valores em array e [array_sum](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) para somar os arrays capturados.

O que seria mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
<?php

$regex = "([\d\.]+\|[\d\.]+)";
$value = str_replace(",", ".", "|5,50|7,00|| |10,0|2,00|| |3,00|30,0||");

preg_match_all("/{$regex}/", $value, $results);

foreach(reset($results) as $result) {
    $values = explode("|", $result);

    var_dump(sprintf("%s = %s", implode(" + ", $values), array_sum($values)));
}
```

Comment: ideone - https://ideone.com/5SOyDx